# London pass travelcard vs. Oyster card

Tags: budget, trains, europe, planning, sightseeing

We are 2 families, 4 adults and 4 kids (age 8, 11, 13, and 16) reaching at LHR 
airport from USA.

Which will better economically save money and time to purchase, Oyster Card or London pass with travelcard?

We'll be able to spend half a day in London on June 1st, all day on June 4th and most of the day on June 5th.

Comment: please, read the http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I edited out the “can you guide me?” questions to focus on the Oyster vs. London pass question because that question seems both specific enough and potentially interesting for other travelers. For the rest, you really need to read the FAQ and ask more focused questions.

Comment: Other questions of interest: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/3-days-in-london-what-do-i-absolutely-have-to-see and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7658/4-days-in-paris

Comment: How long are you going to be in London?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the London Pass worth the price?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/is-the-london-pass-worth-the-price)

Comment: Personally, I am confused by all the information you can find online. Is the London pass Travelcard equivalent to the day cap on an Oyster card?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a really tight schedule, and you know exactly what you want to see and make sure that all the tickets are worth more that the London Pass, then I would say it is not worth it. Buy an Oyster with a Pay-as-you go credit, which you can then return when you fly back and get the remaining money back.

Take a look at this question as well, it is almost a duplicate:
[Is the London Pass worth the price?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/is-the-london-pass-worth-the-price/10649#10649)